# Applying by function to lm()

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am just learning about the `apply` functions and how they work.  I simply want to extract the coefficients from a `lm` fit on a variable x by product color and brand across a several years.

I know I can create a for loop and subset the data by model year and fit it, but I think its time I start using more built in functions, so I want to be able to do it with the by function or one of the apply functions.  Here is what I was thinking.

```
#some made up data

x<-rnorm(50,13400,1200)
color<-sample(factor(c("Red","Black","Blue","Green","White")),50,replace=T)
year<-sample(factor(2006:2012),50,replace=T)
brand<-sample(factor(c("A","B","C","D")),50,replace=T)

d<-data.frame(x,color,year,brand)

#now I want to fit the model lm(x~color+brand) for each year level
#this is what I was thinking...

tmp<-with(d,by(x,year,function(y) lm(x~color,data=y)))
sapply(tmp,coef)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :   numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

I am basing this off the exapmle R gave when I entered `help(by)`

Comment: You are mixing to different paradigms for setting up environments: The `with`-paradigm and the `data=` paradigm. Furthermore, the d$x variable had 50 distinct values, so you would ahve been passing single line dataframes to lm(). Looks like mplourde was able to discern your intent, so I will delete this comment in a bit after you accept his/her answer.

Comment: i suggest you but by "brand" only... and keep it simple... maybe then I will understand how it works

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
tmp <- by(d, year, function(d.subset) lm(x~color, data=d.subset))
```

Comment: I think you may be able to shorten this to `by(d,year,lm,formula=x~color)` since if `formula` is supplied `lm` will match the argument it is given positionally to the next unspecified argument, i.e. `data` ...

Answer (score 5):

In addition to doing this with base R functions (which is a good idea to learn how they work) it's also worth looking at who may have worked on this before. Fitting linear models to each subset of a data set is something that comes up a bunch, and it turns out people have built some convenient tools specifically for this.

Try looking at the package **lme4** and the function `lmList`. From the example in `?lmList`,

```
(fm1 <- lmList(Reaction ~ Days | Subject, sleepstudy))
```

which fits the linear model `Reaction ~ Days` separately for each `Subject`. This is conveient because extractor methods work directly on `fm1`:

```
> coef(fm1)
    (Intercept)      Days
308    244.1927 21.764702
309    205.0549  2.261785
310    203.4842  6.114899
330    289.6851  3.008073
331    285.7390  5.266019
332    264.2516  9.566768
333    275.0191  9.142045
334    240.1629 12.253141
335    263.0347 -2.881034
337    290.1041 19.025974
349    215.1118 13.493933
350    225.8346 19.504017
351    261.1470  6.433498
352    276.3721 13.566549
369    254.9681 11.348109
370    210.4491 18.056151
371    253.6360  9.188445
372    267.0448 11.298073
```

(the row numbers are the id values for the `Subjects`) See the help file at `?lmList` to see what other methods are available for things like confidence intervals, plotting, etc.

Comment: In addition to joran's comments: a) you could also use lmList in package nlme, which has a much better documentation; b) using lmList or many lm on subsets in general is not a good idea. Use the power of lme/lmer  and treat year as a random or fixed effect (use nls in that case).

Comment: Correction to the above: last sentence should read "use gls in that case"

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier in more modern packages, e.g. `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[ , .(reg = list(lm(x ~ color))), by = year]
#    year  reg
# 1: 2012 <lm>
# 2: 2006 <lm>
# 3: 2011 <lm>
# 4: 2008 <lm>
# 5: 2007 <lm>
# 6: 2010 <lm>
# 7: 2009 <lm>
```

The `reg` column has `lm` objects; note we need to wrap `lm` in `list(.)` so that `data.table` doesn't confuse the plain list (note that `is.list(lm(x ~ color, data = d))` is `TRUE`.